# Shifting a byte value

Tags: java, byte

I have following java program:

```
public class java {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte a=64, b;
        int i;

        i=a<<2;
        b=(byte)(a<<2);

        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(b);

    }

}
```

In this program, how the value of **b** is **zero**? I didn't get it.

Comment: Your question is unclear (because it seems obvious that you would get zero). What value were you expecting?

Comment: I am actually not understanding how?? I am new in Java.

Comment: You should convert a's value from decimal base to binary base, in order to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `byte` is exactly 8 bits. And the last 8 bits of your `int` are `0`. If we add the result of [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) like,

```
byte a = 64;
int i = a << 2;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
byte b = (byte) (a << 2);
```

you'll see that the output is

```
100000000
```

so `b` (because the `1` is the ninth bit) becomes

```
00000000
```

(which is 0).